# glClear() not obeying scissor region

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm drawing Open GL content (direct Win32 - not using GLUT, FreeGLUT, GLFW, etc) using double buffering in an arbitrary Windows 7 window which is already open, for example, a Windows Notepad window.  I have the window handle and can draw the content I want as expected, but I am seeing strange behavior with the `glClear()` function.

It is my understanding that the `glClear()` function should only affect pixels on the screen which are INSIDE the region defined by the `glScissor()` function. I have defined the scissor region with `glScissor()` and then enabled the scissor function using `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`. `glClearColor` is set to white `(0,0,0,1)`. I'm clearing both color and depth buffers with the `glClear()` command.

When the `SwapBuffers()` command is executed in order to render on the screen, my selected clear color of white is painted inside the scissor region as I requested, but the rest of the window *OUTSIDE* the scissor region is painted black, rather than leaving these pixels untouched as I expected.

As shown in the image, the scissor region (white) and the object (3D cube) are drawn correctly, but the rest of the notepad window's pixels are set to black, and anything previously painted in that Notepad window is covered over.

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);               // white background
glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300);
glScissor(0, 0, 250, 400);
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//... draw cube inside glBegin()/glEnd()...
SwapBuffers(hDC);
```

Comment: Have you ever cleared the ***entire*** viewport? Buffer swapping can leave parts of the screen that you never clear undefined.

Answer (score 6):

If I get your description correctly, `glClear` works as intended.

You must not assume that only because you see something on the screen, it is also present in the back buffer. The contents of the Notepad window that you see is either the *front* buffer, or a copy of the front buffer that was blitted into DWM's own secret render buffer (depending on whether you have compositing or not). Or, something else, a GDI buffer that was blitted to DWM's buffer, or such. Most likely the latter, since it's using GDI to render.

When you flip buffers, the back buffer is displayed over anything that's on-screen in that regin, and what you get is an all-black buffer (actually uninitialized, but presumably the driver was so kind as to zero the memory) except for the area that you cleared to white.
Which is exactly what you should expect -- your `glClear` affected only a subregion, and the rest is undefined, it *happened to be* zero (black).

Incidentially, *if no compositing is enabled*  what you can see on-screen can be copied from the front buffer to the back buffer on most graphic cards, so you would be able to still see the original contents of the Notepad window if you wished to have it that way. You will however *never* have the contents of a GDI window in your back buffer magically (nor will this work with DWM, nor is it something that is guaranteed to work, it only works incidentially most of the time).

The clean solution, if you want the window's original contents, would be to `BitBlt` from the DC to memory, create a texture, and draw (or blit) that one into the back buffer.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply Damon.  Nice to know this is expected behavior and not some strange issue in my code.  The solution you propose seems like a round-about means for enabling OpenGL to update only a subset of the pixels in a given window during a refresh, but I may give it a shot.  I assume that since pixels outside of my scissor region may be changing based on other unrelated processes, that I will have to re-BitBlt the window every time I update the OpenGL content- this sounds computationally expensive since BitBlt is using CPU rather than GPU, right?

Comment: @user3666612: It _is_ a round trip, but there is no clean way to do it any differently. The "surface" that you draw to (the back buffer) contains either "uninitialized" or what you drew into it, which includes clearing. And that isn't the same surface as the one on-screen (think of clipping or overlapping windows to see that this is obviously not the case). So if you want to have the original window's contents (which is GDI graphics) appear on your OpenGL surface, you must draw/blit/copy that pixel data in there.